# How to install windows sample drivers (blue screen occurs)?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, driver, wdk

I created a sample project with Visual Studio (Filter Driver: Filesystem Mini-Filter) and builded it for x64 platform.

Following [File System Filter Driver Tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43586/File-System-Filter-Driver-Tutorial)
I found that I have to use sc command to install it (run as administrator):

```
sc create FsFilter1 type= filesys binPath= "C:\Users\user\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\FsFilter1\Debug\FsFilter1.sys"
sc start FsFilter1
```

But I still get a blue screen with "system_thread_exception_not_handled", how to check why is that, and how could I resolve it to work poperly?

Is that a proper way of installing windows driver?  or I have to create virtual machine for testing?

I thougth that it is a problem with singing of the driver, but when building with VS - it says:

```
Signability test complete. No errors no waringns everything works fine...
```

So any tips or responses will be greatly appreciated how to start with windows driver development the right way.

I could not imagine that it would be that hard to follow windows documetatnion.

**My Environment:**

- Windows 10 (x64)
- Wdk 10
- Visual Studio 2015
- Set testing on (Bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON)

Comment: you need configure your system for create kernel (or full) memory dump. and after crash open `memory.dmp` in `WinDbg` and research crash reason. or you can debug remote system, where your driver running.

Comment: so your real question - not how install (you really install and load driver in memory) - but how found and fix error in your driver code

Comment: Sorry if it is easy question, but I tried to create a virtualbox machine with windows 10, I provided bridge ethernet connection, so I can see the test pc from my host computer. And I've got error 
    "ERROR: Task "Creating system restore point" failed to complete successfully." Is that normal? I also checked that in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn745909) is said  "Provisioning is not supported for virtual machines." So the question is - Can I create virtual test machine anyway or  I've to buy second pc ?

Comment: of course you can create virtual test machines (usual must be many of this - win7,8, 10 and for x86/x64. may be xp too). not need to by second pc. I have no experience with `Virtualbox` (I worked with `VMware`) but sure with `Virtualbox` this is also possible. "Creating system restore point" - this is very optional thing, not mandatory

Comment: I thought that windows sample drivers should work properly immediately after creation.

Comment: any code can containing errors, so if you view BSOD after start driver - 1)driver really loaded in memory - so you install it OK. 2) exist some error in driver - need or research `memory.dmp` or debug it in runtime

Comment: I finally was able to run "Debugging tools for windows - Kernel debuger" - but it seems not to work. 1) I do not get any debug message (PT_DBG_PRINT) from the driver, 2) the virtual machine does not show BSOD

Comment: 3) Debuger does not break on any break point.

Comment: I found that It could be lack of the "Driver Install Package", but after adding behaviour does not change. I followed  [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665(v=vs.85).aspx) from the begining to end. And I has no driver package in step 9 (first section). I think could be mistake in sample, so I go forward and in step 9 of "Deploy and install the driver" section I has to do "Break all" that not work completly. What should I do with that?

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/develop/troubleshooting-configuration-of-driver-deployment--testing-and-debugging) in section "Debugger breakpoints are not triggered for kernel-mode driver" step 2 - is said that i should stop debugging manually. I mean that "Break all" command do that. Am I wrong?